Usage of 'useState'
I read the posting and something I can't understand is the difference between setValue(curr + 1) and setValue(prev => prev + 1)
Is there anybody who can give me an example in reality so that I can test it on my side?
He called setValue inside the event handler, but what if I call it in another?
Is it a good practice for me to use latter one whenever I use useState?
https://levelup.gitconnected.com/4-usestate-mistakes-you-should-avoid-in-react-0d9d676869e2

Simplest example is just to do it twice in a row. setValue(curr + 1); setValue(curr + 1) vs setValue(prev => prev + 1); setValue(prev => prev + 1). The former increments once, the latter increments twice.

Yeah, absolutely. But what I'd love to know is why this happens.

The setValue(value +  1) is usually used when the current state is not dependent on the previous start, like updating the name.
And this setValue((value) => value+1) is used when the current state is dependent on the previous start.
Below is an example,


import React, { useState } from 'react';

function Counter() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(0);

  const handleDirectUpdate = () => {
    setValue(value + 1);
    setValue(value + 1);
  };

  const handleFunctionalUpdate = () => {
    setValue(prev => prev + 1);
    setValue(prev => prev + 1);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <p>Value: {value}</p>
      <button onClick={handleUpdate}>Direct Update</button>
      <button onClick={handleFuncUpdate}>Functional Update</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Counter;



